# Subtract and multiply by constant each two row's values within same column

Tags: text-processing

I have file with two raws
like this

```
a1  a2  a3   a4 ....  
b1  b2  b3   b4 ....
```

I 'd like to get the result of the following subtraction and multiplication process so the third raw will be the result of all the following term

```
(b1-a1)*c  (b2-a2)*c (b3-a3)*c (b4-a4)*c .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
awk -v c=12 '{print ;} 
      NR==1 { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) F[i]=$i ;} 
      NR==2 { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%d ",($i-F[i])*c ; printf "\n" ;} '
```

where

- `NR` (number of record) select the line.
- `NF` is number of field.
- use `-v c=12` to give value to awk
- unpredictable value if line have different "size"